# How to create a videoThumbnail for remote file?

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-videoview

I am trying to create a video thumbnail for a file :
1- the file is located on YouTube.
2- I would start an implicit intent for Andriod OS to play this file using:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(youTubeVideoWebPath));
startActivity(intent);
```

where

```
String youTubeVideoWebPath = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=OZJalBmtGnQ";
```

after searching some posts on the forum, I found it could be either:
1- VideoView and set its background with the Thumbnail that I will extract from the video Or
2- ImageView which sets its source/background with the extracted Thumbnail

when an item (whether VideoView or ImageView) is clicked, I will send the previous mentioned intent.
since I am not going to control playing the video by my application, I guess that it is better to use ImageView, right?

Secondly, 
I would like to create a video Thumbnail for that remote file so what is the best/easiest way to do that?
For me, after doing more search on the forum, I found the following method:

```
Bitmap thumbAsBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

But it always returns null, I dont know why although that I passed it:
filePath: the web path of the file mentioned above
second argument: not sure whether it should be MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND or 
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND?

I can only find posts related to extracting VideoThumbnail from files saved in internal/external memory, nothing related to remote files such as my case.

Comment: There are already two questions that I have answered myself :)

Comment: Happens :) Still 75% looks less scary than 0% - and at least these questions you answered are now marked answered so others will know you do not need help on them anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not fetch YouTube thumbnail? It looks quite simple. Once you got video URL, like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRpFF5Dm-k0
```

you extract video ID (which in this case is `dRpFF5Dm-k0`) and your thumbnail is at:

```
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEOID>/default.jpg
```

so in this case:

```
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/dRpFF5Dm-k0/default.jpg
```

Not sure if that works for any video (I just found that out to answer your question), but at least it is a good start :)

Comment: I was going to answer the same. That IS the correct answer. You want a thumbnail from YouTube you get it from YouTube.

Comment: This is typically what I have done before I got your answer... Thanks a lot. After searching for about one day trying to create the video thumbnail using andriod APIs, I found out that The data formats of YouTube videos was the most easiest way to get a video thumbnail.